# Questions asking for answer without library

Tags: discussion

I sometimes encounter questions of people asking to solve their problem, but without using library "X". In the JavaScript-tagged world you often see questions that state they don't want to be using jQuery.

Is it still a good idea to post answers that contain a solution using that library (for example posting an answer to use jQuery?). I'm very well aware that this kind of answer does not help the person who asks the question at all.

On the other hand, I think it can be useful for future references for people encountering the same problem but willing to use library "X" (in this example; jQuery). I think there are a lot of questions that gets visited by people who uses Google (and might be allowed to use that library).

What would be the best thing to do for someone who knows the answer with that library but when there's asked not to answer using that library? Is it a good idea to answer that question, or would it be a better idea to create a new question, linking to that question and providing an answer by yourself using that library (Q&A style)?

If the solution is to create a new question, wouldn't it be closed as being a duplicate?

Comment: You could always give both answers. Something along the lines of *"This is how you'd do that, but if you don't have a compelling reason to not do so, here is how simply/safe/trivial it would be with X"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP explicitely excludes some library (like jQuery) or any libraries (asking for plain JavaScript solution) then answering such question with library-based solution wouldn't solve OP's problem and wouldn't be very helpful.

But it strongly depends on the question. Usually you should assume that excluding some/any library has some rational background (for example, I don't want to include jQuery to my mobile site in order to do single trivial thing, or I want to learn how it works, while libraries are hiding that from me).

If OP asks how to connect to Oracle without using library, it's hard to find a rational reason for doing so, but in that case potential answer would be too broad.

I'd add library-based answer to such question only when there's no simple answer without using that library, and you can say from context that OP isn't probably aware of the solution.

Comment: It would not be very helpful for the OP, I understand that, but what about future readers who have the same problem/question but don't share the same rational background? Wouldn't it be better that information using the library (like jQuery) is also shared somehow on SO? I feel that rationale should be avoided as much as possible in questions, because they limit answers that might be useful for future readers.

Comment: @DimitriM there's always the possibility of another question asking specifically for jQuery or some other library for the situation, if the original question stated that they do not wish to use a library.